# NSManagedObjectContext progress meter for saving?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, mbprogresshud

Is there a way to set NSManagedObjectContext to send a message to a delegate periodically as it does complex operations, such as deleting an object with many cascading deletes, or saving changes to disk? I would send the progress updates to a MBProgressHUD controller.

Comment: If your MOC is performing lengthy operations that are blocking the main thread you should consider moving those operations into a separate context/thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way. Is there an easy way? No.

Context's don't save to disk themselves. And Apple strongly discourages subclassing NSManagedObjectContext. The NSPersistentStore is what does the actual serialization/deserialization. You would need to create your own NSPersistentStore that will have an observable progress property or delegate when saving.

Comment: on iOS? No. There is rarely a good use for it. Running the operation in the background is sufficient while possibly showing an indeterminate progress indicator. Truly long running operations like NSMigrationManager do expose an observable progress property.